Cannot connect to wired internet through USB-C hub
I have a laptop connected to a Thinkpad Dock which has an Ethernet jack.
The laptop is running Fedora 40 KDE.
Every time it tries to connect it says "IP configuration was unavailable.".
I have tried disabling IPv6 and setting IPv4 to 'required'.

Check the USB-C port and the dock to see if they are data transfer only.  A lot of them are.
